# Is there an API in C++ for remote inter-process communication?

Tags: c++, networking, ipc

I'm looking for the equivalent of RMI API (in java) in C++ standards. The processes will be running in different machines.

Comment: Google ["C++ Remote Procedure Call"](http://www.google.com/search?q=C%2B%2B+remote+procedure+call)

Answer (score 8):

There are many C++ APIs for inter-process communication. But none of them are part of the C++ standard library.

I suggest using [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/interprocess.html).

But if you're talking across different machines, you need networking, not interprocess communication. That requires a networking library (also not standard); [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) is a reasonable networking library.

Comment: The question was about processes which are running on different machines. Boost.Interprocess is not suitable.

Comment: @KirillV.Lyadvinsky: Good point; it cannot. But [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) can ;)

Comment: Asio can as well as sockets. It's too low-level.

Comment: @KirillV.Lyadvinsky: Asio has many higher-level primitives built on sockets (streams, etc). Whether it is too low-level is for the person asking the question to decide.

Answer (score 3):

C++ Standard can't help you in here. You can use DCOM or Corba (and there are more) depending on which OS you're using.